# Python Selenium - How to specify a client certificate to use in client SSL authentication

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, ssl

I looked at all the possible keys in all json files based on the answer in [Python Selenium - What are possible keys in FireFox webdriver profile preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316910/python-selenium-what-are-possible-keys-in-firefox-webdriver-profile-preference), but I couldn't find a key to specify the client certificate to use in my SSL connection.

I have researched on this, but I couldn't find the exact answer. I found that we need to add the certificate to the FireFox profile based on the answer in [How to import SSL certificates for Firefox with Selenium [in Python]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437407/how-to-import-ssl-certificates-for-firefox-with-selenium-in-python), but I am kind of stuck here, I can't figure out how exactly this certificate needs to be added.

Please note that I am not talking about trusting a server's certificate. By default, when you initiate an SSL connection, a local certificate that is assigned to your workstation is used as the client certificate. Here I need to use a new certificate/private key pair for my SSL connection. I need to do this to test client authentication in SSL.

So, in summary, I am looking for some configuration that looks like this:

```
profile.add_client_cert(path_to_cert)
profile.add_private_key(path_to_private_key)
```

I found a couple of files that might be what I need to tweak, but not sure how to add certificate and keys to these files, `cert8.db` and `key3.db`. I found these files in the FireFox profile directory.

I searched the source code of selenium but couldn't find the answer:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cert

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in the [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py), you could create a firefox profile with a parameter (`profile_directory`) and get firefox launched with the given profile. I think you may also set the preference `profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True`.

The given profile directory should have client certificates prepared.

```
# Prepared Firefox profile directory
profile = FirefoxProfile(profile_diretory)

profile.set_preference("security.default_personal_cert", "Select Automatically")
profile.set_preference("webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs", True)
self.driver = WebDriver(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Comment: Yes @LittleQ, however the question still remains, what is the statement that makes the profile use my certificate and key. Do we have a statement like `profile.add_client_cert(path_to_cert)`? Also, `profile. accept_untrusted_certs = True` makes the client trust the server's certificate, it has nothing to do with client certificate.

Comment: @gixxer The given profile directory should have client certificates prepared(i.e. `cert8.db` and `key3.db` included).

Comment: Hi, when "Select Automatically", one (of many if existing) client certificate will be automatically selected, I understand that. The question is how do I use a specific certificate, in other words, if cert8.db is the db of client certs, it should have only my specific client cert, how do I do that?

Comment: I suggest you do make a cert8.db to include the only one certificate. I think it's easier than code change. @gixxer

Comment: Yes, how do we make cert8.db with only one certificate?

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback on the previous response here's what I did.

In my python code: I have:

```
import os

profile_directory = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.sep),"home","rumpelstiltskin","my_cert_db")
self.driver = WebDriver(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Then to create the `cert8.db` file I used the following terminal commands:

```
cd /home/rumpelstiltskin
mkdir my_cert_db
certutil -N -d sql:my_cert_db/
pk12util -n my-cert-name -d sql:my_cert_db/ -i /my/path/to/cert.p12
```