# How to Cancel user identification request in firefox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox

While running my automation code i have asked to choose this certificate i want to deny this certificate and procced further

[image]

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337976/python-selenium-how-to-specify-a-client-certificate-to-use-in-client-ssl-authe? if it doesn't work you can try with pyautogui